# Using UIGraphicsPushContext(context) and UIGraphicsPopContext()

Tags: iphone, ios, uicolor

Very frustrating experience understanding UIGraphicsPushContext(context) and UIGraphicsPopContext()

My understanding is that I can set attributes of the context like the stroke color and then push the context on a stack so I can set a new color for the current context.  When I'm done doing that I can return to the context by popping it.

Below is my code.  When I run the code below two lines are drawn in blue.  What I expect to happen is: that I first set the color green.  Go to the blueLine function and push the green context.  Draw in blue.  Then pop the green context.  Allowing the drawLine function to drawn in green.

Here is a screenshot of what is drawn (two blue lines): [http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1207310/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Feb%205%2C%202012%209.00.35%20PM.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1207310/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Feb%205,%202012%209.00.35%20PM.png)

Any help is GREATLY appreciated! Thank you.

```
- (void)drawBlueLine:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, 100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width, 200);
    CGContextStrokePath(context); 
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}

- (void)drawLine:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width, 300);
    CGContextStrokePath(context); 
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    [self drawBlueLine:context];
    [self drawLine:context];
}
```

Or shouldn't this work?

```
- (void)drawLine:(CGContextRef)oldContext
{

    UIGraphicsPushContext(oldContext); //makes oldContext the current context but there is a copy on the stack
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    CGContextBeginPath(oldContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(oldContext, self.bounds.origin.x, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(oldContext, self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width, 300);
    CGContextStrokePath(oldContext); 

    UIGraphicsPopContext(); //previous oldContext is moved back into place containing red?
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 

    CGContextRef oldContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [self drawLine:oldContext];
    //anything I draw here should be red.  Shouldn't it?`
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code that actually works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext` does as change which context is being used for drawing, not necessarily save and restore any given context's state. What your code is doing is simply repetitively replacing the context that was current prior to the call to `drawRect:` with the context you grab with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` (they are likely to be the same anyway).

If you want to save an restore a given context's state, use `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState` instead.

Comment: Sorry still confused.  1) Is there any context before drawRect: is called? 2) Where am I replacing a context?

Comment: 1. Yes. It's the current context.

Comment: 2. Technically, you are not replacing the context, you are just popping and pushing the current context. You would use UIGraphicsPushContext with contexts you create (for example).

Comment: What you really want to do is save and restore the context state, which is not the same thing of making the context active or inactive (which is what the pop/push does).

Comment: OK.  Just confused by what I read here from CS 193P (http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%204_1.pdf) and the documentation online (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).  Thanks again.

Comment: There's a correction to the 2013 version of CS193p on this exact issue.  In lecture 6, minute 59, a correction is given:  use CGContextSaveGState(context) and CGContextRestoreGState(context), instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are setting the color, you need to use

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color)

like this:

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor)

and

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor)

so that the color is connected to the context.

[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

is changing the color for all strokes...I'm curious if it would overide the above function if it was set for the context, I think it would not...